# Spray authorized directive not working as expected?

Tags: scala, spray

I'm very new to Spray, so I'm guessing this is just me not correctly understanding how the framework works. However, I'm encountering what seems to be weird behavior when trying to handle. This issue references [this documentation on directives](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/security-directives/authorize/) specifically, but it might apply to other custom directives as well.

When I attempt to utilize the `authorize` directive that Spray ships with, the HTTP response appears correctly according to the returned value. That is, I get a 403 Forbidden when the returned value of `authorize` is `false`, and I get 200 OK when it is instead `true`. However, it seems as though the function passed to it still executes even though it seems like it shouldn't.

Please see [this SBT project](https://github.com/rkoval/spray-test-directive) that I created to test this. It demonstrates my issue exactly, so, hopefully, it's helpful in addressing my concern. Run with:

```
sbt test
```

The output you should see by default should be very similar to the following:

```
[info] Test:
[info] route
[info] - should succeed and have side effects
[info] - should fail and not have side effects *** FAILED ***
[info]   1 did not equal 0 (Test.scala:28)
[info] Run completed in 779 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 1, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 TEST FAILED ***
```

Again, my concern is this: why is the body of the function passed into the `Directive0` of `authorized` executed even when the request is getting rejected?

(Apologies if this is a duplicate. I wasn't able to find a similar issue elsewhere here, but kindly close this issue if you can find one)

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I opened an identical issue on their GitHub Issues page here: https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/1084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of the routing api are explained at http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/.  The key point which is relevant here:

> The mistake of putting custom logic inside of the route structure, but
>   outside of a leaf-level route, and expecting it to be executed at
>   request-handling time, is probably the most frequent error seen by new
>   spray users.

Two contrasting examples are presented in the referenced page.  In this example, the println happens once (at route creation time):

```
val route: Route = get {
  println("MARK")
  complete("yeah")
}
```

And in this example, the println happens with every request:

```
val route: Route = get {
  complete {
    println("MARK")
    "yeah"
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this explains my problem perfectly. It looks like I should peruse more of the Advanced Topics in order to avoid more of these gotchas.

Comment: This seems like a pretty significant flaw with the way spray works.  It appears that both complete blocks, and onComplete blocks trigger rejections to be read (in reality, it's the actor being freed up to process the rejections message).

Imagine spawning a future with a sideeffect, and you need to use the onComplete method of spray. That future will continue to process the side-effect until the onComplete method cancels it when it sees rejections.

Comment: To expand a little more, given [this example](https://gist.github.com/Jacoby6000/250faa7068933ad3eca1), it will always create the object, even in the case of a rejection.

Comment: @JBarber onComplete() takes a by-name parameter, so I'm guessing it won't be evaluated unless the route actually evaluates that directive.  Obviously to get this to work you can't construct the future and assign it go a variable beforehand; you need to pass the future-producing expression as a parameter to onComplete().

Comment: @JBarber alternatively you can reorder your route structure so that the extraction happens after the authorization.  This is because expressions within an extraction are not evaluated until request time.  See "Understanding Extractions" within the page I referenced.

Comment: @JimN I understand the semantics of why what I had stated doesn't work. My only argument is that it is bad by design, and in my opinion should be re-worked to function more intuitively.

Comment: Which is it, "a significant flaw in the way spray works", or "should [...] function more intuitively"?  I agree that there's a bit of a learning curve to overcome.  I initially struggled with it because I was learning scala at the same time.  However once you "get it", it's pretty straightforward.  Hopefully this SO question will help others get it as well.

Comment: It's both. It's a flaw because you can't do certain things without doing a bunch of song dance to avoid the gotcha's like this. In my example, you'd have to redefine the val as `val createdSomething: Unit => Future[DatabaseInsertResult[Something]] = () => somethingRepository.insert(something())`  And then if you wanted to do more complicated things with it, it'd involve a lot of repetition of the same. `val myMappedSomething: Unit => Future[SomethingElse] = () => createdSomething().map(...)` It's very offputting, and using basic features of a library should not require confusing dances.

Comment: Additionally, this kind of problem is likely to be ran in to by many. If anything, it shouldn't be under the "advanced-topics" section.  This is a rather fundamental caveat.